# Как в конструктор поместить переменную enum

Tags: java, enum

У меня есть 2 переменные enum, которые обозначают пол человека.

```
public enum Gender {
    MAN("Мужчина"),
    WOMAN("Женщина");
    private String translation;
    
    Gender(String translation){
        this.translation = translation;
        
    }
    
    public String getGender(){
        return translation;
        
    }

}
```

И я хочу что бы пользователь выбирал какого пола создавать объект класса Person. Например ему выведется на консоль вопрос-"выберите пол человека 1-Муж, 2-Жен".
Он нажимает 1 и в конструктор объекта класса Person вставляется объект MAN.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    

    Gender gen =  Gender.MAN;

    Person person1 = new Person(gen);
    ArrayList <Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    people.add(person1);
    //вывод

}

public class Person {
    private  Gender gen;
          
    public Person ( Gender gen){        
        this.gen = gen;          
    }
}
```

Comment: Не понятно в чём у вас проблема. На первый взгляд всё ОК. Ну и, в качестве шутки, следует заметить, что с таким enum вы вряд ли сможете выйти на европейский или североамериканский рынок с вашей программой)

Comment: Спасибо. Буду Русский Алибаба строить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int input = scanner.nextInt();
Person person1;
if (input == 1) {
     person1 = new Person(Gender.MAN);
} else {
    person1 = new Person(Gender.WOMAN);
}
ArrayList <Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
people.add(person1);
```